# docker asp.net core 2.1 custom port

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm tring to run my asp.net core wep app in docker container using official Microsoft asp.net core 2.1 image. My application uses port 5000 to expose api. This port is configured in custom section of **appSettings.json**

Here is docker command that i use

```
docker container run --rm -p 5000:5000 -v C:\Build\MyApp:/build -w /build  --name coreApp mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 dotnet MyApp.dll
```

Insinde container log I got the following

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /build
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

When I try to go to http://localhost:5000 I get **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**. Seem like container does not map local port 5000 to 5000 inside the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>         Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.

This warning is the key.

Assuming you're using `.UseUrls()`, try `"http://0.0.0.0:5000"` or `"http://+:5000"` in your configuration.

Comment: Yep! changing *localhost* to *0.0.0.0* works. But is there any other way to let docker use *localhost* instead of *0.0.0.0* ?

Comment: No, as far as I know.
What you certainly can do is making environment variables override file configuration settings by building your own `IConfiguration` using `ConfigurationBuilder()` and its option `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`; which will allow you to manage as many variables as you want.

Another alternative for this scenario seems to be using `ASPNETCORE_URLS` env var, but I haven't tried that yet.